# Iron-Router RouteController Inheritance: Why does the Parent Controller's Hook run before the Child's?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've been working with the fantastic Iron-Router package (0.7.1) for Meteor (0.8.1.3) and have run into something that seems somewhat counter-intuitive. I have provided an example below.

The following code was written in context of the Iron-Router's provided Tinytests.
https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/test/both/route_controller.js

```
var Parent = RouteController.extend({
  onBeforeAction: function(pause) {
    console.log('I\'m in the parent!');
    pause();
  }
});

var Child = Parent.extend({
  onBeforeAction: function(pause) {
    console.log('I\'m in the child!');
    pause();
  }
});

var inst = new Child(Router, route, {});
inst.runHooks('onBeforeAction');
```

The test resulted in the Child printing out "I'm in the parent"
I had expected for the Child to print out "I'm in the child"

I feel like with Object Oriented Programming, it would be more natural for the Child's onBeforeAction to override the Parent's.

That being said, if that is intentional, how can I subvert the order of the hooks and have only the Child's onBeforeAction run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is intentional:

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/lib/route_controller.js#L97

```js
// concatenate together hook arrays from the inheritance
// heirarchy, starting at the top parent down to the child.
var collectInheritedHooks = function (ctor) {
  var hooks = [];

  if (ctor.__super__)
    hooks = hooks.concat(collectInheritedHooks(ctor.__super__.constructor));

  return Utils.hasOwnProperty(ctor.prototype, hookName) ?
    hooks.concat(ctor.prototype[hookName]) : hooks;
};
```

If you don't want the parent hook to run, it looks like you'll have to skip using inheritance and do something like mixin common functionality into the various controllers.